# Woocommerce: validate custom fields on my account edit page

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce

I need to validate and save my custom fields in "Edit my account" page. I found template of this page at `woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-account.php`. I managed to add my custom fields in this template file. Now I need to validate them and if it's all good - save user data.

What hook do I need to use in this situation? I can edit `class-wc-form-handler.php` but I don't want to.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add fields using filters and actions? http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Answer (score 2):

I found out an action hook that can be used to validate custom fields or existing fields on Edit Account page. 
Add following code in functions.php.

```
add_action('user_profile_update_errors','wdm_validate_custom_field',10,1);
function wdm_validate_custom_field($args)
{
    if ( isset( $_POST['custom_field'] ) )
    {
        if(strlen($_POST['custom_field'])<6 )
        $args->add( 'error', __( 'Your error message', 'woocommerce' ),'');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

validation of custom fields at edit account page can be done using this action hook, woocommerce_save_account_details_errors

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_process_myaccount_field_{your_custom_field_name}' , 'validate_edit_address' );
function validate_edit_address() {

    $variable = $_POST['your_custom_field_name'];
    if ( preg_match("/[ก-๙a-zA-Z]+$/", $variable ) ){       
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Error</strong>' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $variable ; 
}
```

Example :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_process_myaccount_field_billing_house_number' , 'validate_edit_address' );
function validate_edit_address() {

    $variable = $_POST['billing_house_number'];
    if ( preg_match("/[ก-๙a-zA-Z]+$/", $variable ) ){       
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Error</strong>' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $variable ; 
}
```