# WooCommerce: Validate custom fields on My Account's edit page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, account

I've added custom fields to my WooCommerce registration using [this process](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373-How-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-My-Account-page).
I've made them available on the My Account's edit page using these actions:

```
// added custom fields here
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'my_woocommerce_edit_account_form' );   

// saved user meta here
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'my_woocommerce_save_account_details' );
```

In between the two, I need to validate these fields when editing. I tried using the `woocommerce_process_myaccount_field_` filter ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35330812/4469652)) but that didn't work. The code inside it doesn't trigger when I save the changes.

Any ideas on how can I validate? 
Am I using the correct filter? 
If yes, why doesn't it trigger?

Thanks.

Comment: Which one of them was working for you? thanks

Comment: This one: `woocommerce_save_account_details_errors`. I wonder why this wasn't there in the WooCommerce's Hooks reference on the web..

Comment: Yes it is in **hookr.io**: [woocommerce save account details errors hook](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_save_account_details_errors/) and https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L223

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try to use one of this 2 hooks for validating custom fields.

```
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors','wooc_validate_custom_field', 10, 1 );

// or

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors','wooc_validate_custom_field', 10, 1 );

// with something like:

function wooc_validate_custom_field( $args )
{
    if ( isset( $_POST['custom_field'] ) ) // Your custom field
    {
        if(strlen($_POST['custom_field'])<4 ) // condition to be adapted
        $args->add( 'error', __( 'Your error message', 'woocommerce' ),'');
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this should be added to a filter woocommerce_save_account_details_errors and return $args in all cases?