# To allow only letters in name field in Myaccount page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am working on woocommerce and i am trying to limit the users to specify "only letters" in first and last name field in Myaccount page.What kind of hook should i want  to add in functions.php?

Comment: you may also want to include the hyphen as well as the apostrophe as many have hyphenated names these days and for those with names such as O'Reilly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your function.php and hook below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
$fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = '21343';
$fields['first_name']['label'] = 'name';
$fields['first_name']['pattern'] = '[A-Za-z]';
return $fields;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response,but it is not working for myaccount page

Comment: Have you changed the field name, same as it was right now? I have mentioned first_name, it should be actual field name

Answer (score 0):

> I got a solution

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964514/woocommerce-validate-custom-fields-on-my-account-edit-page)

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_myaccount_field_billing_last_name','billing_last_name_field_validation' );
function billing_last_name_field_validation(  ){
   /* print_r($_POST);
    die;*/


   $value = $_POST['billing_last_name'];
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $value) ){       
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Lastname should contain only letters</strong>' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $value; 
}
```